# Activity not restarting when requesting permission in Android 6.0

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, android-6.0-marshmallow

When am trying to ask for permission the request dialog is appearing and the background is turning black and whatever user press "Allow" or "Deny" the app is closing and not restarting like mentioned in the documentation. This is my code

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Login_Activity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //
            }
            else
            {
                //
            }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: where in the documentation did you see the activity is suppose to restart?

Comment: why vote down?
At least write a comment so that i can under stand what i did wrong so that you vote down my question

Comment: if the app closes, maybe there is an error. please check logcat output and if there is an error, please post it..

Comment: there is no error nothing in the logcat

Comment: The app is not supposed to restart when requesting permissions from it. I think you're thinking of when an app's permissions are manually changed by the user from Settings.

Comment: You described scenario sounds like a crash. Maybe you have set a filter at logcat.

Comment: @tyczj i read it somewhere i dont remember now. So i suppose it should not restart right?
Than where is the problem in this code

Comment: @MikeM. why is the screen background turning to black and acivity is closed

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i had the filters on but nothing appeared

Comment: It really sounds like a crash. Or maybe you've got some code that runs after the permissions dialog that's blocking the UI thread?

Comment: That´s the problem, I guess. Set the logcat to "No Filter" and delete the keyword, then you´ll get the complete logcat...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs nothing really appeared in the logcat i set no filters

Comment: just hypothetically, what will be the next step after getting permission (user clicks allow)? what is your next step (in code)..?

Comment: When user clicks "Allow" onRequestPermissionsResult should be invoked and if permission granted i am just displaying a Toast same when deny also "Deny" is clicked but nothing is invoked

Answer (score 1):

Activity will not restart. Once user granted permission you should call the needed function here.

After user response this method will be called.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // Here you should call the functions whatever you want 
            }
            else
            {
                //If user didn't provide you permission. You will get this else statement. SO you should omit to call the functions(ex. If you requested for the camera access . You shouldn't call the camera functions after user denying permission. If you do app will crash)
            }

        break;
    }
}
```

If you want to restart the class after user gave permission

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Call this function inside the if statement.

Comment: I dont want my activity to restart and did u just copied my code and telling me its the answer?

Comment: Read the commented part @Haidar

Comment: i already know what the if else statements for and that was not my question. My question was why activity is restarting or closing i dont know exactly what is happening and not how to listen to the callback of the allow or deny. 
Sorry not the answer

Comment: Don't call the requested permissions functions in oncreate before user allowing you to access.  That's why you are getting issue. (If you are requesting for camera. You shouldn't call the camera functions inside the oncreate)